# how can I reorder artifactory repositories list

Tags: artifactory

we are using artifactory for remote/virtual/local repositories.

most of those repositories are not interesting to our end user.

is it possible to hide or order the list of the repositories in the UI?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to "limit" the repositories (in your case) is creating virtual repos with only the repos that you want.

For example, if you have this virtual repo:

```
-myvirtualglobalrepo
    -myremoterepo1
    -myremoterepo2
    -mylocal-snahpshot-repo1
    -mylocal-release-repo1
    -mylocal-snapshot-repo2
    -mylocal-release-repo2
```

And for end user are only interesting "myremoterepo2", "mylocal-snahpshot-repo1" and "mylocal-release-repo1" but not "myremoterepo1", "mylocal-snapshot-repo2" and "mylocal-release-repo2" you can create a new virtual repo only with these repos:

```
-myNEWvirtualglobalrepo
   -myremoterepo2
   -mylocal-snahpshot-repo1
   -mylocal-release-repo1
```

In this case, the content of "myremoterepo2", "mylocal-snahpshot-repo1" and "mylocal-release-repo1" are the same in "myvirtualrepo" and "myNEWvirtualglobalrepo" but with the limitation that your users can not see the additional repos that have your "myvirtualglobalrepo".

And your users can use this new repository in your settings.xml file.